# Django smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have a django app that requires users to create an account before they are able to use the service. Upon registration, the user is sent an email with a link to activate their account. Lately however, I have noticed that when someone creates an account with slightly more unusual email addresses than gmail.com, an error is being thrown that the user is 'unknown in the virtual mailbox table (This happens in local, dev and in production). This used to not be the case, but i dont understand what has changed. Full error below (with email address anonymized):

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 881, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'testing@xxxx.com': (550, b'5.1.1 <testing@xxxx.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table')}
```

Do you guys have an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Many mail servers to no accept mails with a sender they don't know. Make use the sender of the registration mails is a valid mail address on that server.

Comment: Hi Klaus, thanks for your comment. Interestingly, this happens also when I try making an account with the same email address that the server is using to send the email in the first place...One would assume that the recipient should accept emails from its own account (or similar emails from the same domain)

Comment: If you are sending with a address that is know to the server, then you have to track the problem in the mail server (and outside of the scope of Stack Overflow).